# Returning 5 best cards containing a pair from a set of 7 playing cards using Python

Tags: python, enums

I'm currently trying to use Python's Enum module on Python 2.7 to identify pair of cards from a hand of 7

```
import collections
import operator
import enum

Card = collections.namedtuple("Card", "rank suit")
#in the below hand there is a pair of fours. 
hand = [
    Card(rank=<Ranks.four: 3>, suit=<Suits.spades: 1>),
    Card(rank=<Ranks.nine: 8>, suit=<Suits.clubs: 3>),
    Card(rank=<Ranks.ten: 9>, suit=<Suits.spades: 1>),
    Card(rank=<Ranks.jack: 10>, suit=<Suits.diamonds: 4>),
    Card(rank=<Ranks.six: 5>, suit=<Suits.hearts: 2>),
    Card(rank=<Ranks.four: 3>, suit=<Suits.diamonds: 4>),
    Card(rank=<Ranks.two: 1>, suit=<Suits.clubs: 3>),
    ]

#My function
def is_pair():
    #count duplicate-numbers in `hand`
    ranks = collections.Counter(map(operator.attrgetter("rank"), hand))
    pair_card=[]
    if len(ranks) == 6:
        # get most common if there are individual counts
        # (so one is duplicated and not counted)
        pair_card = ranks.most_common(1)[0]6
    for i in hand:
        print i
    print pair_card
    print type(pair_card)
```

The above code will recognize a pair but I want it to return the 5 best cards, which would be the pair of cards plus the three highest (as per the rules of Poker). So my question is how can I get the above function to return any pair from any 7 cards, along with the other three highest cards?

So in this case, the desired output is:

```
output = [
    Card(rank=<Ranks.four: 3>, suit=<Suits.spades: 1>),
    Card(rank=<Ranks.nine: 8>, suit=<Suits.clubs: 3>),
    Card(rank=<Ranks.ten: 9>, suit=<Suits.spades: 1>),
    Card(rank=<Ranks.jack: 10>, suit=<Suits.diamonds: 4>),
    Card(rank=<Ranks.four: 3>, suit=<Suits.diamonds: 4>),
    ]
```

That's to say, removal of the 2 of clubs and 6 of hearts.

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried that calculates the other 3 cards? You have tried this yourself already, right?

Comment: You don't say which Enum module you are using -- `enum34` is the backport of Python 3.4's `Enum` module.

Comment: I'm just using `import enum` on Python 2.7

Comment: If the answer solved your problem you should accept and up-vote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your Rank enum also a subclass of `int`?

If so, just order the remainng cards and take the last three.

If not, add ordering:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, Rank):  # or self.__class__ instead of Rank
        return NotImplemented
    return self.value < other.value
```

Comment: Hi Ethan, Rank was built using `enum.IntEnum` i.e. `Ranks = enum.IntEnum("Ranks", "two three four five six seven eight nine ten jack queen king ace")`

Comment: @user3059024: Then once you have removed the pair you should be able to do `hand.sort()` and take the last three.